# MapReduce - Generate HDFS path

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to generate HDFS path on my mapper code. FileSystem has all the method that we can do from CLI like put, get, mkdir etc... but not getting when a directory already exists in the HDFS, how to generate its path in my mapper or reducer code.

I am using `MR2`..

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by generate path?

Comment: Please see my comments below.

Comment: Why do you want to generate code in Mapper or Reducer code?

Answer (score 0):

read `input.txt` from `HDFS`

```
  public class HdfsRead {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            String uri = args[0];

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
            FSDataInputStream in = null ;
            try
            {byte [] buffer = new byte[256];
                in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
                    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);    

            }
            finally
            {
                IOUtils.closeStream(in);
            }   
        }
    }
```

check file if already exist, delete it

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path path =  new Path(args[0]);
if(fs.exists(path)){
    fs.delete(path);
}

commandline argument 
args[0] = "hdfs://localhost:9000/input.txt"
```

Comment: In your example hdfs://localhost:9000 is kind of hardcoding but when we will move our code into cluster (production), this code will not work. Suppose, I created a folder "mydir" in hdfs and I want to generate its path like hdfsURL + path.Seprator + "mydir" for further processing. How we can do this?

Comment: @Ajay You can pass hdfsUrl from the command line or set it system property and later read it in your job.

Comment: Is there any alternate way to get this within our code? I mean thru configuration of FileSystem API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setup() menthod in Mapper/Reducer code and create directory using FileSystem API . If you want to check that directory/file already exists then use "exists" method from FileSystem class.